# scrreprt LuaLaTeX Error: incompatible 'everysel' detected. \if@raggedtwoe@footmisc

Tags: incompatibility, ragged2e

I updated all my packages, then got this error. I installed the package everysel in the MiKTeX Console, but this didn't help. Everysel is called by the package ragged2e, which I need. I need to compile with LuaLaTeX

I deleted all files before compiling again, but to no avail.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}
```

log file:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (MiKTeX 21.8) (format=lualatex 2021.8.30)  30 AUG 2021 10:46
 restricted system commands enabled.
**ragged2e.tex
(./ragged2e.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2021-05-21 3.18 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/
2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2021-05-20.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2021-05-20.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.116
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/
2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 4
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' at position 1 in `input_level_string'.
(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/scrre
prt.cls
Document Class: scrreprt 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script document class (repo
rt)

(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkb
ase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-depend
ent basics and keyval usage)

(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/scrba
se.sty
Package: scrbase 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-indepen
dent basics and keyval usage)

(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlf
ile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlf
ile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX h
ooks)

(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlo
go.sty
Package: scrlogo 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script package (logo)
))) ("C:/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] compatibility for LaTeX before 2021/05/01 on inpu
t line 339.
))
(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/tocba
sic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files
)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box50
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 137.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrreprt)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 248
6.

(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsi
ze11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script font size class option 
(11pt)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/Mi
KTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script/typea
rea.sty
Package: typearea 2021/06/03 v3.34.3603 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count179
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1742.
)
\c@part=\count180
\c@chapter=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\chapter on input line 5716.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5727.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5727.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrreprt)           for `\part on input line 5736.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5746.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5746.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5756.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5756.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5767.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5767.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5777.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5777.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip60
\belowcaptionskip=\skip61
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box51
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6957.

\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@figure=\count187
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6974.

\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@table=\count188
Class scrreprt Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7143.
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty
Package: ragged2e 2019/07/28 v2.2 ragged2e Package (MS)

(C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty
Package: everysel 2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
)

! Class scrreprt Error: incompatible `everysel' detected .

See the scrreprt class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.146 \if@raggedtwoe@footmisc
                           
You are using an old version of `everysel' in combination with a LaTeX
version >= 2021/06/01 and KOMA-Script >= 3.33. This combination is
not supported.
You could switch back to an older LaTeX using package `latexrelease'.
But I recommend to update `everysel'

\CenteringLeftskip=\skip64
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip65
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip66
\CenteringRightskip=\skip67
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip68
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip69
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip70
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip71
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip72
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip73
\CenteringParindent=\skip74
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip75
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip76
\JustifyingParindent=\skip77
) ("C:/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def"
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count189
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
) (./ragged2e.aux)
\openout1 = ragged2e.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 8
.

("C:/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \contentsname on input line 8.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listfigurename on input line 8.
Package scrbase Info: activating english \listtablename on input line 8.

ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros

LaTeX Warning: Command \selectfont   has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 8.
[1

{C:/Users/Anne/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(./ragged2e.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 3525 strings out of 478146
 100000,552014 words of node,token memory allocated
 496 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 66 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:27,3:4,4:1,5:27,6:2,7:52,9:24,11:3
 23854 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 23 fonts using 2647927 bytes
 108i,7n,102p,10602b,272s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<//?/c:/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on ragged2e.pdf (1 page, 3775 bytes).

PDF statistics: 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: We probably need to see an example document that triggers this error. You mentioned miktex, did you update in 'user mode' and 'admin mode' (if you have both on your system).

Comment: @daleif I only have user mode of the MikTeX console installed. I added an MWE to my question.

Comment: show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added it

Comment: Your ragged2e package is outdated, you have a version from 2019, I have `ragged2e 2021/02/05 v3.0`. Beside this you mixed up your pathes. The KOMA-classes are in `MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tex/latex/koma-script`, while ragged2e  is `MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/ragged2e`. See the double `tex/latex`. ? I have no idea how you managed to do this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer neither do I. I moved koma-script to the tex folder higher up (it was the only thing in that nested folder, which I deleted). I also deleted the outdated ragged2e folder. Everything runs now, thank you! (It seems that my MikTeX console installs updates into a different folder. I have to sort that out.)

Comment: hm. And where is ragged2e from now?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer from the folder into which MikTeX console updates packages, which is `C:/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex` (as opposed to `C:/User/AppData/Roaming/MikTeX/2.9/`etc.). As I said, I need to sort this out. I think it happened when I uninstalled and reinstalled MikTeX console. Would it be safe to delete the entire MikTeX folder from AppData/Roaming?

Comment: No it is not safe. If you start to delete and reinstall parts of miktex there is always the danger that you mess up things -- as you just learned. And I will certainly not start to make a diagnose or even suggest a therapy only based on some vage descriptions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's fine, I wasn't looking for a solution for this. Your "No" is all I needed to hear. I only answered because you asked where ragged2e was now. I'm sorry if I made you feel like I was expecting a whole solution from you. I wasn't.